# SQLAlchemy load_only option doesn't work, but returns all columns, not just specified columns

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I am using SQLAlchemy and the [`load_only`](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/orm/loading_columns.html#sqlalchemy.orm.load_only) option.
After I read `load_only` docs, I expect that if I use `load_only`, I can get some specified columns. But the result is not. There were all columns, not some columns. I don't know why. Can you give me some advice?

ps. I need row-entity, so I don't use query like this:

```
session.query(table.columnA, table.columnB)
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q0BDk.png)

I am using SQLAlchemy 1.3.4

```
class Language(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'language'
    IDX = Column(INTEGER(11), primary_key=True)
    DH_INDEX = Column(ForeignKey('dryhop.DH_INDEX', ondelete='CASCADE', onupdate='CASCADE'), index=True)
    EP_INDEX = Column(ForeignKey('expendables.EP_INDEX', ondelete='CASCADE', onupdate='CASCADE'), index=True)
    LANG_CLASS = Column(String(20), nullable=False)
    LANG_NATION = Column(String(15), nullable=False)
    LANG_COMMENT = Column(Text)
    UPDATE_TIME = Column(DateTime, server_default=text("CURRENT_TIMESTAMP"))

query= session.query(db_model.Language).options(load_only("LANG_COMMENT", "LANG_NATION"))
dir(query.first()) # 'DH_INDEX', 'EP_INDEX', 'IDX','LANG_CLASS', 'LANG_COMMENT', 'LANG_NATION', 'UPDATE_TIME'... ETC
```

When `dir(query.first())`, I expected only two columns

```
'LANG_COMMENT', 'LANG_NATION')
```

but result is

```
'DH_INDEX', 'EP_INDEX', 'IDX','LANG_CLASS', 'LANG_COMMENT', 'LANG_NATION', 'UPDATE_TIME'
```

Comment: SQLA models do not implement `__dir__`, so the names are gathered in the usual fashion. There's nothing out of the ordinary in the result.

Comment: @Ilja Everilä thanks answer!. So you means that load_only query returns all columns not specified columns, right? But i understand that load_only returns only some columns. In that query, i can get values, query.DH_INDEX.. Is this right? i expected only two column's value

Comment: @Ilja Everilä i checked that select query is different(using sqlalchmy echo =True). Also i checked your answer(https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50317889/in-sqlalchemy-why-is-my-load-only-not-filtering-any-columns-that-i-have-specifi). If so what is difference between normal query and load_only query?, I read docs but i can't get any benefits using load_only options. And Thank you very much Ilja Everilä. You helped me last time. I appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given an object, the builtin [`dir`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#dir) attempts to return a list of valid attributes for that object. If the object in question does not override the default functionality by implementing [`__dir__()`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__dir__), the list is produced for "ordinary" objects as such:

> Otherwise, the list contains the object’s attributes’ names, the names of its class’s attributes, and recursively of the attributes of its class’s base classes.

In other words the list you get is both a list of the loaded attributes (among others) from the instance, and the attributes from the class `Language`, its parent, and so on.

If you wish to verify that only the attributes you wanted are loaded, you can for example peek at the instance's [`__dict__`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#object.__dict__) attribute, using [`vars()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#vars):

```
In [11]: vars(query.first())
Out[11]: 
{'IDX': 1,
 'LANG_COMMENT': 'Comment',
 'LANG_NATION': 'bar',
 '_sa_instance_state': <sqlalchemy.orm.state.InstanceState at 0x7fa6414916d8>}
```

Or even better, use SQLAlchemy's [runtime inspection](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/core/inspection.html):

```
In [37]: from sqlalchemy import inspect

In [38]: obj = query.first()

In [39]: inspect(obj).unloaded
Out[39]: {'DH_INDEX', 'EP_INDEX', 'LANG_CLASS', 'UPDATE_TIME'}
```

Finally, note that no matter what you put in [`load_only()`](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/orm/loading_columns.html#sqlalchemy.orm.load_only), the primary key is always loaded, because [it would not make sense not to](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54158098/2681632), even if you [really wanted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44842959/sqlalchemy-using-load-only-with-distinct).

Comment: Thank you very much Ilja Everilä. Every question, i owed you. Thanks !!!